# Why does the 737NG EGT drop during take-off?

Tags: jet-engine, takeoff, boeing-737, egt

I noticed that the EGT drops a bit when I hit TO/GA for take-off on a 737-800.

Comment: I think you may add some context (it may depend on ambient pressure and temperature)

Comment: @ManuH Seems like a perfectly valid question to me.

Comment: @J.hougaard I agree. Adding context will bring this question from valid to well documented.

Comment: Is this observed in the aircraft, the simulator, or in a program on a computer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [image]

Above is takeoff engine data$^1$ and is indicative of the behavior you've mentioned. (FF is fuel flow and TLA is thrust lever angle.) The same behavior can be seen here as well:

- A [737-800 takeoff video](https://youtu.be/lZmZ-ebPvIE?t=50)
- An "[EICAS cam](https://youtu.be/pWcp2Se5Dfk?t=81)" video for what I think is a 777
- An [Embraer E190-E2 video](https://youtu.be/NHoIiv3Ojb8?t=79)

(The exact timing may depend on how long the engines are left in the stabilization process.)

Note: The 737NG EGT sensors are at the T495 station in the low pressure turbine section. There are 9 thermocouple probes and their average is displayed.

The CFM56 employs [variable stator vanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_compressor#Bleed_air,_variable_stators) (VSV) in the compressor. In general those vanes close at low engine speed and open at high engine speed *(shown below).*

> [image]
>   Source: CFM56-5A manual

The specifics are proprietary, but plausible conclusions can be made. When the engines are stabilized for TO/GA, it could be the ECU (electronic control unit) opening the VSV to provide the ideal compressed air for faster engine acceleration (more air before the fuel would lower the EGT).

Note: The VSV is controlled by the hydromechanical unit (HMU), which receives input (torque motor current) from the ECU ([CFM presentation](http://www.smartcockpit.com/docs/CFM_Flight_Ops_Support_B737.pdf), PDF page 16).

---

*Of course if you have cause for concern, don't use the internet for flight, and check with your airline.*

$^1$ Lion Air Max crash [report](http://knkt.dephub.go.id/knkt/ntsc_aviation/baru/pre/2018/2018%20-%20035%20-%20PK-LQP%20Preliminary%20Report.pdf) (sadly the only public source of FDR data I can think of is accident reports).

Comment: wow sir thank you, i am not an engineer by background any may need some time to process this. but it's quite interesting to know why!